# Insert each array value into new line in Laravel Blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Now when I have my sorted and counted array I want to display the result on the blade template. The page looks like this

```
@foreach($best as $info)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
               <span class="col-xs-6 "><strong>User Number:</strong></span> {{ $info->user_id }}
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                 <span class="col-xs-6">Username:</span> {{ $info->username }} 
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <span class="col-xs-6">Points:</span>
                    @foreach($sums as $value => $sum) 
                         {{$sum}} 
                    @endforeach
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

In the controller nothing fancy:

```
$best = Users::all();
$sums = array_count_values($product_ids);

return View::make('users.statistics', [
        'best' => $best,
        'sums' => $sums
]);
```

The part which is problematic is this one in the blade

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="col-xs-6">Points:</span>
        @foreach($sums as $value => $sum) 
            {{$sum}} 
        @endforeach
</div>
```

If I have two users I should get output like

```
User Number       Username         Points
    1               user1            10
    2               user2            11
```

Instead because of this second foreach I've got (**note the points column**)

```
User Number       Username         Points

    1               user1           10 11
    2               user2           10 11
```

Is there a way to manage each points on it's own row

```
var_dump($product_ids);
array(5) { 
    [0]=> int(2) 
    [1]=> int(1) 
    [2]=> int(1) 
    [3]=> int(1) 
    [4]=> int(1) 
}
```

Comment: Can you show what looks like your $product_ids array ?

Comment: I've updated the question. Basically those are ID's of users.

Comment: i've updated my answer. use $info->user_id instead of $key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
@foreach($best as $info)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
               <span class="col-xs-6 "><strong>User Number:</strong></span> {{ $info->user_id }}
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                 <span class="col-xs-6">Username:</span> {{ $info->username }} 
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <span class="col-xs-6">Points:</span>
                    {{$sums[$info->user_id]}} 
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

You are using a method named `array_count_values`. That counts all the values of an array.

I guess that `$products_ids` is an array containing users id. 
So if your `$products_ids` looks like :

```
array(1,2,1,3,4,4)
```

`array_count_values()` will return something like :

```
[user_id] => int(number_of_times_that_user_id_appear)
```

So :

```
array(4) { 
   [1]=> int(2)
   [2]=> int(1) 
   [3]=> int(1) 
   [4]=> int(2) 
}
```

So user **1** have **2** points, user **2** have **1** point, user **3** have **1** point and user **4** have **2** points.

More documentation about the function here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: I've got `ErrorException: Undefined variable: key`

Comment: Okay, this is working. Can you explain me a little bit? Sorry, I'm not sure I understand it.